# What is the largest code point for 16-bit wchar_t type?

Tags: c, utf-16, wchar-t, widechar

It is said [here](http://www.unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html) that UTF-16's largest code point is `10FFFF`

Also it is written on that page that

> BMP characters require one 16-bit code unit to process or store.

But in bit representation `10FFFF` is

```
0001 0000   1111 1111   1111 1111
```

We see that it occupies more than 15 bits of 16-bit `wchar_t`
(an implementation is allowed to support wide characters with >=0 value only, independently of signedness of `wchar_t`)

What is the *real* largest code point for 16-bit `wchar_t`?

Comment: Do you understand the difference between “code point” and “code unit”?  Or know how UTF-16 works?

Comment: @dan04 "code point" is the number, designated to each letter. I don't know how UTF-16 works. I tagged it because 16-bit `wchar_t` is said to use UTF-16. And I don't know what a "code unit" is.

Comment: @dan04 Do you know which maximal value for codepoint can be stored in a single variable of 16-bit `wchar_t` type?

Comment: UTF-16 code unit is 16 bit, hence it is UTF-16. But the largest code point 10FFFF requires 2 units (2 wchar_t), so called surrogate pairs. Single  wchar_t (assuming 16 bit) can only encode some 63K characters of entire 21^2 space.

Comment: @Flanker please put the maximal codepoint value which can be stored in a single variable of 16-bit wchar_t to the answer so that I could upvote

Comment: Max valid char value for UTF-16 single code unit would be FFFD or so called replacement character (FFFE & FFFF are non chars) - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specials_(Unicode_block)

Comment: UTF-16 is a variable-length encoding, just like UTF-8.  A codepoint requires 1 or 2 wchar_t, just like UTF-8 requires 1, 2, 3 or 4 char.  So the question is the rough equivalent of "what is the real largest codepoint of a char".  Not a sensible question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> It is said here that UTF-16's largest code point is 10FFFF

Yes, but you are misinterpreting the table that you are drawing that from.

U+10FFFF is the largest Unicode **code point** value.  UTF-16 is not Unicode itself, it is an *encoding* of Unicode code points using **16-bit code units** (just as UTF-8 is an *encoding* using 8-bit code units) .  As you remarked, 16 bits is not enough to represent the full range of Unicode code point values.  The UTF-16 encoding of Unicode code points U+0000 - U+FFFF requires only 1 code unit, but the encoding of code points U+10000 - U+10FFFF requires 2 code units acting together, known as a "surrogate pair".  UTF-16 is the successor to UCS-2, which was the original 16-bit encoding for Unicode but it could only encode code points U+0000 - U+FFFF.  UTF-16 is backwards compatible with UCS-2, but adding surrogate pairs allows UTF-16 to support the full range of Unicode code points.

UTF-16 is designed so that the code unit values from which surrogate pairs can be formed are reserved for that purpose.  They cannot be misinterpreted as regular characters, even when they appear unpaired (in what therefore must be an invalid code sequence).

Note also that it's a bit of an abuse, albeit a common one, for a C implementation to call UTF-16 (or UTF-8) a "character set", as their code units do not all correspond 1-1 with Unicode characters.  Or, at least the characters to which they correspond have to be interpreted as the code units that they are.  It's a pragmatic approach to the problem of efficiently representing characters from a large range.

> Also it is written on that page that
>
> > BMP characters require one 16-bit code unit to process or store.

That is also true.  You apparently have overlooked the fact that BMP (Basic Multilingual Plane, code points U+0000 - U+FFFF) characters are a subset of all Unicode characters. 1/17th of them, in fact, or somewhat less, depending on how you count. The fact that their code point values can all be represented with 16 bits (i.e. in one UTF-16 code unit) could in fact be taken as a definition of that subset.

> We see that it occupies more than 15 bits of 16-bit wchar_t (an
>   implementation is allowed to support wide characters with >=0 value
>   only, independently of signedness of wchar_t)

No, as we covered in my answer to [one of your other recent questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40755634/2402272).  The standard imposes no restriction on C implementations to support only non-negative code point values.  That's just the *de facto* state of the code point assignments of all current, widely-used coded character sets.  A conforming C implementation on which `wchar_t` is signed could provide a character set in which some extended characters have negative corresponding `wchar_t` values.

> What is the real largest code point for 16-bit wchar_t?

That has nothing to do with any of the foregoing.  In fact, it doesn't make much sense.  Code point values are a characteristic of (coded) character sets, not of any C data type.  They are the numbers corresponding to the characters supported by that set.

If a C implementation claims to provide UTF-16 as a supported character set, then it follows that its `wchar_t` must have at least 16 value bits, because that type must be able to represent all UTF-16 code unit values.  If that type has only 16 bits altogether then they must all be value bits, making the type necessarily unsigned, and capable of supporting values up to `0xFFFF`.